# PDF Form Creator (like crystal reports) for Python 2.7 app (Linux and Windows)

Tags: python, forms, python-2.7, pdf, crystal-reports

I'm looking for an app similar to Crystal Reports, that can generate pdf forms from a MariaDB database. My app is made in python 2.7 and it runs on Linux OS and Windows OS. I need this app to generate invoices from my app.
  I found some projects on GitHub but they were not so GUI friendly. I need this app to be able to let me generate the form by using a GUI, after I generated the custom form the app should access it and print the invoice on screen, where the user will choose to save or print.
  I'm new to python, I started to code 6 month ago, I could use your help for my problem, and I thank you all.